# Getting state of predictions in LSTMs

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am attempting to generate shakespeare text using the following model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len_vocab, 64))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len_vocab, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

The training set consists of characters converted to numbers. Where `x` is of shape `(num_sentences, sentence_len)` and same shape for `y`, where `y` is simply `x` offset by one character. In this case `sentence_len=40`.

**However, when I predict I predict one character at a time**. See below for how I fit and predict using the model:

```
for i in range(2):
    model.fit(x,y, batch_size=128, epochs=1)

    sentence = []
    letter = np.random.choice(len_vocab,1).reshape((1,1)) #choose a random letter
    for i in range(100):
        sentence.append(val2chr(letter))
        # Predict ONE letter at a time
        p = model.predict(letter)
        letter = np.random.choice(27,1,p=p[0][0])
    print(''.join(sentence))
```

However, regardless of how many epochs I train all I get is jibberish for the output. **One of the possible reasons is that I do not get the cell memory from the previous prediction**.

So the question is how do I make sure that the state is sent off to the next cell before I predict?

Full jupyter notebook example is [here:](https://github.com/sachinruk/deepschool.io/blob/master/Lesson%2014%20-%20LSTM%20Shakespeare%20generator%20-%20Solutions.ipynb)

#### Edit 1:

**I just realised that I would need to send in the previous LSTMs hidden state and not just cell memory**.
I have since tried to redo the model as:

```
batch_size = 64

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len_vocab, 64, batch_size=batch_size))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len_vocab, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

However, now I cannot predict one letter at a time as it is expecting a `batch_size` of inputs.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py)?

Comment: @Yu-Yang I'm afraid this is not what I want. That's a many to one prediction (i.e. 40 letters used to predict one letter in my scenario). Mine is very specifically on how to pass the state onto the next element question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @j-c-doe pointed out you can use the stateful option with batch of one and transfer the weights. The other method that I found was to keep unrolling the LSTM and predicting as below:

```
for i in range(150):
    sentence.append(int2char[letter[-1]])
    p = model.predict(np.array(letter)[None,:])
    letter.append(np.random.choice(len(char2int),1,p=p[0][-1])[0])
```

NOTE: The dimensionality of the prediction is really important! `np.array(letter)[None,:]` gives a `(1,i+1)` shape. This way no modification to the model is required.

And most importantly it keeps passing on the cell state memory and hidden state. I'm not entirely sure if `stateful=True` if it passes the hidden state as well, or if its only the cell state.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to train a char-rnn with Keras can be found in the official example: [lstm_text_generation.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

This model is trained based on sequences of maxlen characters.
While training this network, LSTM states are reset after each sequence (stateful=False by default).

Once such a network is trained, you may want to feed and predict one character at a time. The simplest way to do that (that I know of), is to build another Keras model with the same structure, initialize it with the weights of the first one, but with RNN layers in Keras "stateful" mode:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, len(chars))))
model.add(Dense(len(chars)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

In this mode, Keras has to know the complete shape of a batch (see the doc [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)). 
Since you want to feed the network only one sample of one step of characters, the shape of a batch is (1, 1, len(chars)).